# Uniform convergence on compact subsets of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I know that for a continously differentiable $2 \pi$ periodic function $f \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ its Fourier series converges uniformly  and that if I only suppose that the function is continous everywhere and continously differentiable except that for a finite number of points, where $f$ admits right and left derivative , there is pointwise convergence.

I was asked to prove that in this second situation, we have uniform convergence on the compact subsets of $(-\pi,\pi)$ that do not contain any of the points where the derivative isn't defined.

I tried to write the Fourier serie as convolution of $f$ with $D_n$, the Dirichlet kernel and refining the standard estime about the pointwise convergence, but i wasn't able to find a uniform condition because that estime is made by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which does not seem uniform in any way to me.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

On intervals where $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ with a left derivative at $a$ and a right derivative at $b$, integration by parts gives a uniform Riemann-Lebesgue estimate:
$$
    \int_{a}^{b}f(t)e^{-int}dt= \left.f(t)\frac{e^{-int}}{-in}\right|_{a}^{b}+\frac{1}{in}\int_{a}^{b}f'(t)e^{-int}dt.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but i cannot understand: what do I care about integral over $(a,b)$??

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio : So you can work on intervals where the derivative exists and obtain a uniform Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.